# Why the method event listener click works only first time in for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, dom, addeventlistener, onclicklistener

i want to run the function "checkSlotsChoosen" every time i click on the buttons "slotsAvailables" and on "buttonBooking" but it works only for the first click, in every buttons. I add console.log to see how it works.
Do you know why? Thank you in advance!

[image]

```js
<script>
var buttonBooking = document.querySelector('.pbSubmit');
var slotsAvailables = document.querySelectorAll('.availableslot a');

buttonBooking.classList.add('disable');

function checkSlotsChoosen(){
        var slotsChoosen = document.querySelectorAll('.availableslot.currentSelection');
        var slotsCancel = document.querySelectorAll('.cancel');

        if(slotsChoosen.length === 0){
                buttonBooking.classList.add('disable');
                console.log('disable btn');
        }else{
                buttonBooking.classList.remove('disable');
                console.log('active btn');
        }

        for (let b = 0; b < slotsCancel.length; b++) {
            slotsCancel[b].addEventListener('click', checkSlotsChoosen);
        }
    }



for (let a = 0; a < slotsAvailables.length; a++) {
    slotsAvailables[a].addEventListener('click', checkSlotsChoosen);
}


buttonBooking.addEventListener('click', checkSlotsChoosen);
<script>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML markup to your question. You can use the snippet tool `[<>]` in the edit toolbar to create working code using the HTML/JS, and any CSS. It makes it easier for you to describe the problem to us, and for us to help debug the problem.

Comment: Hi!
You have many issues to address in your code. You are attaching event listeners many times. You don't want to do that, instead put a single event listener on the parent tag which checks which element was clicked. Then, I'm not sure why are you are adding the event listener inside the callback function... Intent is not too clear, maybe you could elaborate on what you need your script to do and I can provide a more detailed answer. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks guys for quickly reply. 
I'm not being able to add a class to the HTML I had to insert many event listeners. I added the event listener for the .cancel button because it appears after the function is fired

Comment: @JoV as I mentioned in my comment it's important for us to see your HTML markup so that we can place your code in context. Please add the markup to your question as a [mcve] using the snippet tool.

Comment: Thanks @Andy but the HTML is too long, is over the limit of stackoverflow

Comment: Ah, ok, I think I can see what you're trying to do. You have a list of times which you can click on and the chosen time(s) appear below. You can cancel the times. But the main function is checking to see if any times have been selected. If none have been selected disable the booking button otherwise enable it? @JoV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is re-apply event listeners to the items in the list of selected times because you're dynamically adding them. This is probably the wrong way forward.

As subparry mentions in their comment you can add one listener to a containing element that can catch events from its child elements as they "bubble up" the DOM - a process known as [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/).

In this example (I had to make up the HTML based on your image) I've got three sections - one for the time buttons, one for the list, and one for the form (represented by just the "Book" button here).

For the time button section and the list section I've added *one* event listener to each.

Whenever a time button is clicked its parent `section` element catches the event, checks to see if [the element that was clicked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) was a time button, and its handler creates a new list element (the time button's text content, and a cancel button), and adds it to the list. It then checks if the book button is disabled and enables if it is.

When a cancel button in a list item is clicked the event listener on the container is triggered, and its handler called. The handler checks to see if the element that was clicked was a cancel button, finds its [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) list item element, and removes it. It also performs a check to see if the list has any children remaining and if it doesn't, disables the button.

Summary: with event delegation there's no longer a need to add event listeners on dynamically created elements.

```js
// Cache the containers, and the book button
const times = document.querySelector('.times');
const list = document.querySelector('.list');
const book = document.querySelector('.book');

// Add two listeners to the times buttons
// and the list sections
times.addEventListener('click', handleTime);
list.addEventListener('click', handleList);

// When the handleTime handler is called it
// checks that the clicked element has a "time"
// class, creates a new list item, and adds it
// to the list. If the "book" button is disabled
// it enables it
function handleTime(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('.time')) {
    const time = e.target.textContent;
    const item = `
      <li>
        ${time}
        <button
          type="button"
          class="cancel"
          data-time="${time}"
        >Cancel
        </button>
      </li>`;
    list.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', item);
    if (book.disabled) book.disabled = false;
  }
}

// When the `handleList` is called it checks to
// see if the clicked element has a "cancel" class,
// removes its closest list item (ie its parent element)
// and disables the book button if there are no longer any
// list items in the list
function handleList(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('.cancel')) {
    e.target.closest('li').remove();
    if (list.children.length === 0) {
      book.disabled = true;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="times">
  <button class="time">10:15</button>
  <button class="time">10:45</button>
  <button class="time">11:15</button>
  <button class="time">11:45</button>
  <button class="time">12:15</button>
</section>
<section>
  <ul class="list">
  </ul>
</section>
<section class="form">
  <button
    type="button"
    class="book"
    disabled
  >Book</button>
</section>
```

Comment: Tanks very much! it works